# Why is this through association in Sails causing an error

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I have two models: `Species` and `Lands` with a third model serving as the join table `SpeciesLands` allowing me to add additional attributes t.

Multiple species can occur on the same land. A single species can occur on multiple lands (M:M relationship). The following setup worked in SailsJS `v0.12.13`, but not when I upgraded to `v1.x`.

### Error message

*A `through` property was set on the attribute `species` on the `lands` model but no reference in the through model was found.*

### Models

My models are as follows (with unrelated attributes removed for brevity):

#### Species.js

```js
  attributes: {

    ...

    lands: {
      collection: "lands",
      via: "land",
      through: "specieslands",
      description: "A species can be associated with one or more public lands"
    }

  },
```

### Lands.js

```js
  attributes {

    ...

    species: {
      collection: 'species',
      via: 'species',
      through: 'specieslands',
      description: 'A public land can be associated with one or more species'
    }
  }
```

### SpeciesLands.js

```js
  attributes: {

    population: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      isIn: ['O+', 'O', 'P', 'U']
    },

    species: {
      model: 'species'
    },

    land: {
      model: 'lands'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your `via` attributes pointing to the wrong thing. They are the "pivot" point, if you will, to which the through association hinges. Also, you have `land` pluralization inconsistently in your collections.

Try something more like this:

#### Species.js

```js
  attributes: {

    ...

    lands: {
      collection: 'land',
      via: 'species',
      through: 'specieslands',
      description: 'A species can be associated with one or more public lands'
    }

  },
```

### Lands.js

```js
  attributes {

    ...

    species: {
      collection: 'species',
      via: 'land',
      through: 'specieslands',
      description: 'A public land can be associated with one or more species'
    }
  }
```

### SpeciesLands.js

```js
  attributes: {

    population: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      isIn: ['O+', 'O', 'P', 'U']
    },

    species: {
      model: 'species'
    },

    land: {
      model: 'lands'
    }
  }
```